# What would cause Build Configuration not to recognize new Build Config setting?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017 ,I have defined a new Build Config using Configuration Manager called LiveSystemBuild

I have set all projects as AnyCPU . I have some code as follows:

```
#if LiveSystemBuild
    private const string custID = "1234;
#else 
    private const string custID = "9876";
#endif
```

The problem is that I have set the build as LiveSystemBuild, i would have expected the line

```
  private const string custID = "1234;
```

to be enabled , but its not. It doesnt seem to recognize the new build i have defined.

Do I need to define it anywhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the new created configuration `LiveSystemBuild` did not add itself into `DefineConstants` property. So you should add it manually into `csproj` file.

**First**, you should create the new configuration `LiveSystemBuild` under **active solution configuration**. If not , you should remove them and add it under **active solution configuration**.

[image]

**Second**, add this at the bottom of every project's `csproj` file.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='LiveSystemBuild'">
        
  <DefineConstants>TRACE;LiveSystemBuild</DefineConstants>
        
</PropertyGroup>
```